# NavigationBarButton is not getting Hidden but hides when viewWillAppear method is called?

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar

```
func setupRightNavigationItems()
    {
        let menuButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        menuButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu-white").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),for:.normal)
        menuButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        menuButton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:25,height:25)

        let playButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        playButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "nowplaying32").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        playButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        playButton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:25,height:25)

        let nowPlaying = defaults.string(forKey: "NOWPLAYING")
        if nowPlaying == "true"
        {
            playButton.isHidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            playButton.isHidden = true
        }

        menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(notificationPlayButtonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView:menuButton),UIBarButtonItem(customView:playButton)]

    }
```

The button gets hide when i called this function i.e setupRightNavigationItems in viewWillAppear but it does not reflect the changes of button getting hide inside the view, when i call it from another function after checking the condition please help !.

Comment: Hi, check my answer. It works fine. I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to hide

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

Comment: this method is also not working its getting nil but the changes are not reflected to the view but when again called from viewWillAppear then only the changes can be shown

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working good. Just check your condition is correct or not.

```
class DemoVC: UIViewController {

    var flag = "true"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupRightNavigationItems()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        flag = "false"
        setupRightNavigationItems()
    }

    @IBAction func onBtnChange(_ sender : UIButton) {
        flag = "true"
        setupRightNavigationItems()
    }

    func setupRightNavigationItems()
    {
        print("called")
        let menuButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        menuButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "likesong").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),for:.normal)
        menuButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        menuButton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:25,height:25)

        let playButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        playButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "likesong").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        playButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        playButton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:25,height:25)

        let nowPlaying = "true"//defaults.string(forKey: "NOWPLAYING")
        if nowPlaying.lowercased() == flag.lowercased()
        {
            playButton.isHidden = true
        }
        else
        {
            playButton.isHidden = false
        }
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView:menuButton),UIBarButtonItem(customView:playButton)]
    }

}
```

i'm calling this function from `viewDidLoad` and working good.i just added static condition for test.

On `touchesBegan` button get visible and on `onBtnChange` again get hidden.

Try this, Hope this work.

Comment: yes it perfectly works from viewDidLoad but when i call it from another function the navigation bar does not reflect the changes but the button gets hidden . it works perfectly fine in viewWillAppear as well as viewDidLoad.

Comment: @SmiteshWadher `navigation bar does not reflect the changes` what changes you want?

Comment: the button to actually get hidden

Comment: @SmiteshWadher i made changes take a look once

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below to hide and show a navigation button

**Hide:**

```
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .clear
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
```

**Show:**

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = yourbuttonTint color
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right it won't hide when called from function other than `willAppear` or `didLoad` , because both bar button items are already created. You can't simply hide it,

So before calling this function, remove `rightBarButtonItem`, Now every thing will be OK.

Try this,

```
@IBAction func hideNavigationBar(_ sender: UIButton) {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
    setupRightNavigationItems()
}
```

Try This too

```
    let nowPlaying = defaults.string(forKey: "NOWPLAYING")
    if nowPlaying == "true"
    {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView:menuButton),UIBarButtonItem(customView:playButton)]
    }
    else
    {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView:menuButton)]
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: it still does'nt work i dont want to call it on a button i m calling an api and from there i m sending the key as true and when the button is hidden it should unhide directly without touching anything.

Comment: @SmiteshWadher  I had used IBAction just for a reference, u can call it from any where as you want. Since you are calling this inside a API call make sure you had dispatched in main queue.

Comment: yes i have dispatched it inside the main queue but still it only gets affected when view is appeared again not while i m in the view

Comment: gokul i just tried this now only doesnt get affected still stuck in this issues since last 14 hours

Comment: @SmiteshWadher okay, to figure out issue create a sample project and test this function alone, trigger it with a button action. So that we can have a clear idea

Comment: @SmiteshWadher I have tested this as sample project. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to set nil first, then set the buttons to refresh view.

```
func setupRightNavigationItems() {
    // here your rest code

    // set nil here >>>
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView:menuButton),UIBarButtonItem(customView:playButton)]

}
```